# How to parse text in multiple body tags with BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to parse this website: https://www.flyingv.cc/project/3724

and I want fetch the information in the html source code.

Just like this information, 2830:

```
<span class="sharenumber" id="fb_share_span">2830</span>
```

But when I use BeautifulSoup to extract text between span tags, it is totally failed.

My python codes are:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get("https://www.flyingv.cc/project/3724") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
test = soup.find('span', attrs={'id':'fb_share_span'})
print test
print test.txt
```

The output of python is:

```
<span class="sharenumber" id="fb_share_span"></span> 
None
```

How can I extract the information in the scenario?
Furthermore, this website has multiple body tags.
So I suspect this is the reason why I failed, but I don't know how to handle this kind problem.

Thank for your help, and sorry for that my English is very pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data/value you want is not rendered by https://www.flyingv.cc. It's received in this XHR (AJAX) call:

https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=json&method=links.getStats&urls=https://www.flyingv.cc/project/3724

Which outputs something like this:

```
[{
    "url": "https:\/\/www.flyingv.cc\/project\/3724",
    "normalized_url": "https:\/\/www.flyingv.cc\/project\/3724",
    "share_count": 466,
    "like_count": 1995,
    "comment_count": 369,
    "total_count": 2830,
    "click_count": 0,
    "comments_fbid": "673240602745001",
    "commentsbox_count": 0
}]
```

So if you want to get every project's **`total_count`** value (which is a sum of **share_count** + **like_count** + **comment_count**) just change **`urls`** variable content in the above link.

---

This code could help:

```
#coding:utf-8

import json
import requests

url_prefix = "https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=json&method=links.getStats&urls="
project_url = "https://www.flyingv.cc/project/3724"
response = requests.get("{}{}".format(url_prefix, project_url))

data = json.loads(response.content)[0]
print data.get('total_count', None)
```

Output:

```
2830
```

Comment: It is perfect!!! Thank for your help!!!
And I am sorry for that I have another problem....
I also want to extract the information, 1,201 按讚次數, which is the count of Facebook fan-page's like.

But I don't know how to handle this question, too.
I am sorry for that....
Really Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Hey @陳冠穎 I'm glad my answer helped. Please don't forget accepting my answer if it helped you solve the problem. Regarding Facebook fan-page's likes, I can help you with that tomorrow.

Comment: Really thanks for your help!!!  I have struggled against these problems for a long time....but still failed....